# NPM install Gulp/Elixir

Tags: node.js, laravel, npm, gulp, laravel-elixir

I'm following a course online and have downloaded Node and NPM.

I have done a package.json file and are have some problems with
the installation.

I really don't understand the error message. I had the latest
version of Node, I tried to downgrade the version to 6.10.3 (the same version in the online course) but I still don't work.

Is there someone here that knows what the problem can be? I'm new at this and not so experienced with the error messages.

```js
{
    "author": "Erika",
    "description": "Jewelry Shop",
    "private": true,
    "dependencies": {
        "gulp": "~4.0.0",
        "laravel-elixir": "~5.0.0"
    }
}
```

$ npm install
npm WARN deprecated babel-preset-es2015@6.24.1:   Thanks for using Babel: we recommend using babel-preset-env now: please read babeljs.io/env to update!
npm WARN deprecated gulp-util@3.0.8: gulp-util is deprecated - replace it, following the guidelines at https://medium.com/gulpjs/gulp-util-ca3b1f9f9ac5
npm WARN deprecated minimatch@2.0.10: Please update to minimatch 3.0.2 or higher to avoid a RegExp DoS issue
npm WARN deprecated browserslist@0.4.0: Browserslist 2 could fail on reading Browserslist >3.0 config used in other tools.
npm WARN deprecated minimatch@1.0.0: Please update to minimatch 3.0.2 or higher to avoid a RegExp DoS issue
npm WARN deprecated hoek@2.16.3: This version is no longer maintained. Please upgrade to the latest version.
npm WARN deprecated boom@2.10.1: This version is no longer maintained. Please upgrade to the latest version.
npm WARN deprecated cryptiles@2.0.5: This version is no longer maintained. Please upgrade to the latest version.

> node-sass@3.13.1 install C:\httpdocs\ecommerce\node_modules\node-sass
>   node scripts/install.js

Cached binary found at C:\Users\Erika\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache\node-sass\3.13.1\win32-x64-48_binding.node

> node-sass@3.13.1 postinstall C:\httpdocs\ecommerce\node_modules\node-sass
>   node scripts/build.js

Binary found at C:\httpdocs\ecommerce\node_modules\node-sass\vendor\win32-x64-48\binding.node
Testing binary
Binary is fine
npm notice created a lockfile as package-lock.json. You should commit this file.
npm WARN acorn-dynamic-import@4.0.0 requires a peer of acorn@^6.0.0 but none is installed. You must install peer dependencies yourself.
npm WARN optional SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: fsevents@1.2.4 (node_modules\fsevents):
npm WARN notsup SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: Unsupported platform for fsevents@1.2.4: wanted {"os":"darwin","arch":"any"} (current: {"os":"win32","arch":"x64"})

added 1299 packages from 772 contributors and audited 17546 packages in 89.815s
found 11 vulnerabilities (8 moderate, 2 high, 1 critical)
  run `npm audit fix` to fix them, or `npm audit` for details

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Which portion of this message log are you concerned about?

It seems like it added the packages for you:

```
added 1299 packages from 772 contributors and audited 17546 packages in 89.815s
```

It just had some warnings displayed as well. The warnings may key in to potential issues when running whatever program you are trying to run afterwards, however, without any specific issue, you are probably fine.

The deprecated and unsupported warnings can be possibly fixed by installing the latest versions of the packages that you are using, but there is no guarantee that the package maintainers have updated their dependencies to suit.

To upgrade a package and save it you can use the following command:

```
npm -i --save gulp@latest laravel-elixir@latest
```

`-i` for install, `--save` to save this back in your dependencies in your `package.json`.

Comment: It was the warnings in general I was concerned about but now I understand. Thank you for clarifying :)